# xUnit .NET Core Multiple InlineData inputs with respectively different expectations

Tags: c#, .net-core, xunit

```
        [Theory]
        [InlineData("atv,atv,atv,hdm")]
        [InlineData("nx9,nx9,atv,nx9,nx9,nx9")]
        [InlineData("nx9,nx9,atv,nx9,nx9,nx9,nx9")]
        public void Buy3Pay2(string input)
        {           
            var co = new Checkout(rules);

            var stock = input.Split(',');

            foreach (var item in stock)
            {
                var product = products.SingleOrDefault(p => string.Compare(item, p.SKU, true) == 0);
                Item realItem = new Item() {
                    Name = product.Name,
                    SKU = product.SKU,
                    Price = product.Price
                };
                realItem.ID = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
                co.Scan(realItem);
            }

            var total = co.Total();

            total.Should().Be(249.00M);
            //total.Should().Be(531.00M); for the second input
            //total.Should().Be(698.00M); for the 3rd input
        }
```

How can I set the expected results according to different InlineData input?

Comment: add it (the expectation) as an input also and use that for assertion

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add it (the expectation) as an input also and use that for assertion

For example

```
[Theory]
[InlineData("atv,atv,atv,hdm", "249.00")]
[InlineData("nx9,nx9,atv,nx9,nx9,nx9", "531.00")]
[InlineData("nx9,nx9,atv,nx9,nx9,nx9,nx9", "698.00")]
public void Buy3Pay2(string input, string expected) {
    //Arrange
    var co = new Checkout(rules);

    var stock = input.Split(',');

    foreach (var item in stock) {
        var product = products.SingleOrDefault(p => string.Compare(item, p.SKU, true) == 0);
        Item realItem = new Item() {
            Name = product.Name,
            SKU = product.SKU,
            Price = product.Price
        };
        realItem.ID = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
        co.Scan(realItem);
    }

    //Act
    var total = co.Total();

    //Assert
    total.Should().Be(Convert.ToDecimal(expected));            
}
```